# Orthogonal distance regression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, least-squares

Given two random variables/measurements (*x*, *y*), both measured with error (error-in-variables case),
 is there a routine in MATLAB to calculate the estimators (*a*, *b*) of a regression line *y*(*i*)=*a*·*x*(*i*)+*b* using the method of orthogonal distance regression?

Here's my implementation of Maximum Likelihood estimator:

```
x= [1.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.4, 0.2];
y=[0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2];

mx = mean(x);
my = mean(y);
p = (x(:) - mx) .^ 2;
q = (y(:) - mx) .^ 2;
w = p .* q;
sxx = sum(p);
syy = sum(q);
sxy = sum(w);    w=p.*q;   sxy=sum(w);

l = 1;  %# orthogonal distance regression
a = (syy - l * syy + sqrt((syy - l * sxx) ^ 2 + 4 * l * sxy^2)) / (2 * sxy);
b = my - a * mx;
```

---

**EDIT** (addressed to EitanT):

Here's a comparison of my estimators and yours:

[image: comparison]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't have a built-in function *exactly* like that, but you can easily find the estimators *a* and *b* with [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/svd.html) approximation<sup>1,2</sup>:

```
data = [x(:), y(:)];
[U, S, V] = svd(data - repmat(mean(data), size(data, 1), 1), 0);
a = -V(1, end) / V(2, end);
b = mean(data * V(:, end)) / V(2, end);
```

Which is in fact the orthogonal distance regression method.

**EDIT #1:**
Here's a plot of the original data, alongside my estimator and yours.

[image: comparison]

Your estimator is highly inaccurate, which brings me to believe that that your implementation is flawed.

**EDIT #2:**

Here's an updated plot if the computation of `a` is corrected to:

```
a=(syy-l*syy+sqrt((syy-l*sxx)^2+4*l*sxy^2)) / (2*sxy);  %# Forgot parentheses!
```

[image]

Closer, but still not as accurate as mine.

**EDIT #1:**

You can further improve the accuracy of `sxx`, `syy` and `sxy`, like so:

```
cov_mat = cov(x, y);
sxx = cov_mat(1, 1);  %# Same as: sxx = var(x);
syy = cov_mat(2, 2);  %# Same as: syy = var(y);
sxy = cov_mat(1, 2);  %# Same as: sxy = cov_mat(2, 1);
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Gene H. Golub and Charles F. Van Loan (1996) *"Matrix Computations"* (3rd ed.). The Johns Hopkins University Press. pp 596.](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares#Algebraic_point_of_view)</sup>

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the matrices U, S and V and I can't find any similarity with the orthogonal distance regression method (ODR). I run an example using the above code and the equations of ODR and the estimators are different in each case. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: In the ODR we assume that λ is known and equals 1 (meaning the two error variances are the same) and in the geometric mean functional relationship λ= Syy/Sxx.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27918-gmregress/content/gmregress.m

Comment: Ah, okay. I found it too, but it is a user implementation, not official.

Comment: I don't know when they added this, but there's now an official documentation page on essentially this algorithm: https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-an-orthogonal-regression-using-principal-components-analysis.html

Comment: @jhin Thanks for keeping my answer alive :-). It's not surprising that a lot has changed in the official documentation since 2012 (when I wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

I ran the algorithms above: (1) Maximum Likelihood Estimator (2) The orthogonal distance regression method (3) MINITAB's orthogonal regression all for the same five (x,y) data points.  I added the absolute value of the residuals of each regression and got the following:
    red    green    black
  0.7748   0.5137   0.4485
where the red line is method (1), green is MINITAB method and (3) black line is the svd orthogonal distance regression.  The black line gave the lowest absolute value residual sum.
Here is the comparison on a plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S90W.jpg)